# How to combine for loop output with another for loop output?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, zip, output, associate

Let's say I have a loop that generates random names

```
names = ['Kiri', 'Elizabeth', 'Philip', 'Charlotte', 'Lydia']

random_names = []
for x in range(3):
    random_names.append(random.choice(names))
print (random_names)
```

-This would print out random 3 names e.g ['Charlotte', 'Lydia', 'Kiri']

Then I want to generate random numbers, lets say from 1 to 20

```
random_numbers = random.sample([x for x in range (1,20)], (3))
print (random_numbers)
```

And lets say we got [7, 13, 2]

Then my question is, I want to assign these random numbers to following random names so that it is associated with the name. How should I write the code in a way so it can appear as

('Charlotte', 7), ('Lydia', 13), ('Kiri', 2)

Thanks in advance
!

Comment: Just use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html?highlight=zip#zip) to combine the two lists `zip(random_names, random_numers)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several way for doing it you can use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html?highlight=zip#zip) look this little example:

```
names = ['Kiri', 'Elizabeth', 'Philip', 'Charlotte', 'Lydia']
random_numbers = random.sample([x for x in range (1,20)], (3))
zip(names,random_numbers)
```

output

> [('Kiri', 19), ('Elizabeth', 3), ('Philip', 1)]

The output above is a `list of tuples`

Comment: The issue is I am using python 3, so it seems like I can't use that as error occurs - <zip object at 0x101ac0188>

Comment: Okay I found out that for python 3, I have to add list infront. So list(zip(names,random_numbers)). Thanks